# aws attach volume on bootup and mount it before apache mysql ... starts

Tags: amazon-web-services, upstart

ubuntu 14 amazon aws

i am trying to attach and mount a volume on startup
i having the following .conf file in /etc/init

```
start on started network-interface
script
/usr/bin/aws ec2 attach-volume ... && /bin/mount ... || /bin/mount ...  
end script
```

the problem is the attaching is asynchronous and could take any arbitrary time

so if i startup an instance the first time
it attach the volume but will fail on the mount if i reboot then it will
fail on the attach as it is already attached the mount will work then
any subsequent reboot will work the problem is the first time when the volume
needs to be attached

so i think i will need a second script (not sure if i can do it in the same .conf file) 
something like

```
start on started network-interface
script
////try to attach it if we get an error then its already attached so mount it
/usr/bin/aws ec2 attach-volume ... || /bin/mount ...    
end script

start on WHEN volumen IS attached (no idea what i need here)
script
///new device attached to system mount it
/bin/mount ...
end script
```

so my question is how do i know when a device/volume is attached to the system
i hope all that can be done before anything like apache mysql ... starts
if not i would in addition need to restart them or better delay the start of apache mysql ... till my mount is ready
p.s i need to attache multiple volume in this way

appreciate any advice

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using /etc/fstab to auto mount the file system on boot?

Comment: i do other things in there attaching ip setting dns i would like to have it all in one place and fstab wouldnt solve the problem that there is nothing to mount till i havent attached the volume

Answer (score 0):

1. By having the instance create and attach its own EBS volume, each instance will need AWS credentials or an IAM instance role that allows it to create and attach EBS volumes.  This is potentially a security risk.
2. If you must have the instance create its own volume (still less than optimal), don't use `upstart`.  This only needs to be done once, at first boot, not on every reboot.  Pass the commands in the instance `user-data` as a script to be executed at first boot.
3. Better yet, create the instance with the volume and have it attach automatically.  Make an autoscaling group and put the EBS volume in the launch configuration.  (Autoscaling groups don't have to autoscale.  You can force them to be an exact size.  They are immeasurable useful for automating creation of instances with complex configurations.)  Then in the `user-data`, pass a script that formats the volume and mounts it (and adds an entry to `/etc/fstab`).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: see above was to long to post it as a comment